# IOS Calling UIButton from a string variable

Tags: ios, for-loop, uibutton

I am looking for a better way to set images to all of my buttons. Right now I am using a for loop but having to call each button individually. It's ugly and way too long.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *box0;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *box1;
// up to 150 of them on the page
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *box150;

@end

@implementation HelpTwo
{
    bool checked0;
    bool checked1;
    bool checked2;
    bool checked3;
}
```

**and the part in question**

```
NSArray *boxes = [draftboxeschecked componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    // pulled from DB and as an example could be 0,1,8,19,29

NSInteger i;
for (i=0; i < boxes.count; i++) {
    NSString *box = boxes[i];
    if ([box isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        [_box0 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked0 = YES;
    } else if ([box isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [_box1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked1 = YES;
    }
    else if ([box isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        [_box2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked2 = YES;
    }
    else if ([box isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        [_box3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked3 = YES;
    }

// all the way to 150
```

**What I am trying to do instead but it isn't working**

```
NSArray *boxes = [draftboxeschecked componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for (NSString *boxNumber in boxes) {

    NSString *modifiedBox = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_box%@",boxNumber];
    bool check = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"checked%@",boxNumber]; 

    [modifiedBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    check = YES;  
}
```

**EDIT:**

This seems to be working for the image. Still need to add the boolean value.  I added all of the buttons to a IBOutletCollection and set tag numbers to each. The collection is named buttonCollection.

```
NSArray *boxes = [draftboxeschecked componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for (NSString *boxNumber in boxes) {

    for (UIButton *button in _buttonCollection) {
        if (button.tag == boxNumber.intValue) {
            // set image
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues in your code:  
  
 1. modifiedBox is an NSString. NSString does not support setImage   
 2. You are creating your local variables in a loop, you should do that outside   
 3. check is a bool, but you assign it an NSString  
 4. check does nothing  
  
Too many issues in code. Maybe you can post more code to make it clear, or you describe better what you try to achieve

Comment: Do you have 150 buttons on the IB? a solution would be to use tag and then get the appropriate button based on tag. Have you considered using UITableView with button embedded. This isn't an efficient way of creating 150 buttons in a uiviewcontroller

Comment: The uiviewcontroller has 150 buttons that act as checkboxes when clicked. They are for choosing options on that page. The part I am working on is if they save a "draft" and want to come back later I am setting the correct image (checked or not checked)  The boolean is for the segue to know which boxes were checked so they can be added to an array

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you're using checked_# for. Here's a solution (but I don't recommend it necessarily). I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the check bool, so I've left it out.

```
NSArray *boxes = [draftboxeschecked componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (NSString *boxNumber in boxes) {
  NSString *boxSelectorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"box%@", boxNumber];
  // Assuming the properties are on the self object, they should create selectors that
  // match the property name.
  // Note: I'm not familiar with IBOutlets.
  UIButton *boxButton = [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(boxSelectorString)];
  [boxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I was going to try that but the buttons are already set. I just need to reference them. This is for pre loading an image based on if it had been previously "checked" and that is the reason for the boolean.

Comment: This doesn't create new buttons, just accesses the ones that already exist as properties of HelpTwo.

You could add an array of NSNumber booleans if you want to track each button being checked, or use a NSMutableDictionary